# Running a method based on an attribute's value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, methods, import

A rails 4 application has a functionality to import data via csv

```
def self.import(file, analyse_id)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, :col_sep => "\t", headers: true, skip_blanks: true) do |row|

  begin
   MyClass.create(
     [...]
   )
  rescue StandardError => e
    puts "Error importing row because '#{e.message}'"
    puts row
  end
end
```

Contextually, many users may have data structured differently. Thus three dynamics variables are at play: file, analyse and the import method.  Having the data pre-determined, I assume that creating a text_area variable (say `@user.import_method`), one could insert the proper method (or segment thereof) there and use it in the execution of another method.

However, my inner voice says there are pitfalls here (aside from banal coding errors).  Is this possible (with both the full and partial_method approaches)?

Comment: i think i don't understand your problem completely, but why don't you just use a select box instead of your text area?

Comment: @Fallenhero User one may have order of variables, A, B, C, D, while user two may have the order D, A, E, C, B, G.  The users know nothing of each other, but their data structure is **predetermined**  What did you have in mind when you state `select_box`?

Comment: ah i think now i understand. `A`, `B`, ... are the fields in your csv but users might have them in different order and possibly only a subset.

Comment: yes, that is the case

Comment: In that case can't you just assign user variables to indices of the csv array? all not set variables will have higher indices and will have values = nil

Comment: so the import_method would have `:code_id => row[@user.variable_a], :description => row[@user.variable_b]` and the user table would include these variables...  basically refactoring all the CSV method variables into individual table data...  Sounds right.